# LINQ Group By and aggregate fields

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, group-by

I've always struggled with grouping in LINQ, I'd like to group based on the date part of a datetime field and aggregate other fields.

Example table layout

```
myDateField     myIntField1    myIntField2    myIntField3
01/02/2013      5              5              5
01/02/2013      5              5              5
02/02/2013      10             10             10
02/02/2013      10             10             10
```

I'd like to return a list with

```
myDateField     myIntField1    myIntField2    myIntField3
01/02/2013      10             10             10
02/02/2013      20             20             20
```

I've managed the following using msdn examples but can't really get my head around how to use it. It states I should be able to access the new `BookedList` group but keep getting annonymous type errors and such.

```
        Dim bestdays = From a In b
                        Where a.BookedOn < a.EventDayTime And a.Cancelled = False
                        Group By BookDate = a.BookedOn.Value.Date
                        Into BookedList = Group
```

Comment: [.Take(n)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) does this for you (where n is the *number of contiguous elements from the start of a sequence*). Or is your question about the errors you're getting?

Comment: Sorry @DaveRook the title is maybe misleading, I know how to get 5 records, my code above doesn't seem to group though. It also doesn't aggregate the myIntFields. I know how to do this in SQL - SUM all the myInt fields and then group by the datefield, how can I accomplish this with LINQ-SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is `Into [FIELD_NAME1] = [AGGREGATE_FUNCTION1]([VALUE1]), [FIELD_NAME2] = [AGGREGATE_FUNCTION2]([VALUE2]) ...`. The key will automatically be part of returned object.

So you are looking for something like this:

```
Class TableRow
  Public Property myDateField As Date
  Public Property myIntField1 As Integer
  Public Property myIntField2 As Integer
  Public Property myIntField3 As Integer
  Sub New(mydate As Date,
          myint1 As Integer, myint2 As Integer, myint3 As Integer)
    myDateField = mydate
    myIntField1 = myint1
    myIntField2 = myint2
    myIntField3 = myint3
  End Sub
End Class

Sub Main()
  Dim tablesRows As New List(Of TableRow)
  tablesRows.Add(New TableRow(Today, 5, 10, 15))
  tablesRows.Add(New TableRow(Today, 6, 11, 16))

  Dim v = From r In tablesRows Group By r.myDateField
          Into Total1 = Sum(r.myIntField1),
               Total2 = Sum(r.myIntField2),
               Total3 = Sum(r.myIntField3)
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! not only an answer but I think you've helped me get my head around how this works too. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this sld do your job

```
Dim bestdays = (From a In b
               Where a.BookedOn < a.EventDayTime And a.Cancelled = False
               Group By BookDate = a.BookedOn.Value.Date
               Into BookedList = Group).Take(5)
```

Comment: Thanks Manolis, please see comment above, have change title as realise that may be misleading, I know how to get 5 records, but my group by isn't working.

Comment: Try this : Group By a.BookedOn